# Do Salesforce1 Mobile App users on cellular always have to verify their login

Tags: salesforce1-app, security, login

This is an admin question rather than coding:

I have an SF1 user that has to validate their login virtually every time that they login to SF1.

The user has an iPad Air running iOS7 with a cellular connection. Being on celullar he will have dynamic IP addresses.

There is no issue with restricted IP ranges, nor login hours.

Personally I'm office bound, so I don't seem to have a problem, but is this normal for SF1 users on celullar?

Thanks for any insight!

BTW: I have also posted this question on Salesforce Success:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Mobile&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=90630000000iBXDAA2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the user should not have to login that frequently. I use S1 on cellular data all the time without having to re-login. What should happen is, when they login, S1 is given an access token (with session lifetime) and a refresh token (indefinite lifetime). S1 should save the refresh token to the iOS keychain. After their session times out, S1 should send the refresh token to Salesforce and receive a new access token, allowing it to access APIs again.

So, what could be going wrong? As an admin, it's possible to control the lifetime of those refresh tokens. Go to **Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps** and look for Salesforce1. Click it, and look for 'Refresh Token Policy'. If that is set to, for example, 'Immediately expire refresh token' or 'Expire refresh token after 1 day', it could be causing the behavior he's seeing.

I'm not sure why different users are seeing different behavior, though. It could be some subtle interplay between IP address, profile and refresh token policy.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Pat, I've learnt a lot about the token usage and OAuth thanks to your insightful answer.  I've checked the OAuth usage for the users and they have the same token that they've been using a great deal.  I'm now thinking that they're actually meaning that their session has timed out, so I've extended the timeout period a little. Thanks for a good answer! BTW: I was at Warwick Uni in 98 - had a good time there!